Implementing a grpc async service with streaming
I managed to implement a grpc async server handling of multiple types of requests thanks to this answer.
Unfortunately I'm failing at having one of those methods returning a stream of messages
service MyService {
    rpc StreamSequence(MyServiceStreamRequest) returns (stream MyServiceStreamResponse);
}

message MyServiceStreamRequest {
    int64 id = 1;
}
message MyServiceStreamResponse {
  repeated string entries = 2;
}


I tried modifying the CallDataT specialization to introduce an additional
grpc::ServerAsyncWriter<ReplyType> streaming_responder_;

instead of the
grpc::ServerAsyncResponseWriter<ReplyType> responder_;

but I don't know how to handle the logic in Proceed() afterwards (this returns a stream writer, also that stream writer should be alive during all of the processing I guess).
Does anyone have any clue how should I implement a grpc async service with streaming?
